# error on uploading hippo cms on real server

Tags: hippocms

I've got hippogogreen with maven and it's archetype.
I've done my changes and I've made my site.
I want to upload it on a real server,
I copied it's site.jar on webapp directory of tomcat on server, but it doesn't work.
I do every thing in this document http://www.onehippo.org/7_8/library/deployment/deploy-a-project.html 
but I think  there is some more thing to do.
and also I want to know if somebody has experience with hippo how does manage it for developing and deploying?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you seen the documentation?

http://www.onehippo.org/7_8/library/deployment/deploy-a-project.html